# Querying external etcd with prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, etcd

I've got prometheus running ontop of kubernetes with the following scrape config, as described by the documentation. Where the .pem files are located on disk within the prometheus container.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: etcd
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['10.0.0.222:2379','10.0.0.221:2379','10.0.0.220:2379']
  tls_config:
  # CA certificate to validate API server certificate with.
    ca_file: /prometheus/ca.pem
    cert_file: /prometheus/cert.pem
    key_file: /prometheus/key.pem
```

I see that etcd as a target in prometheus, however its returning garbage.

https://i.imgur.com/rdRI4V7.png

I am able to hit the metrics endpoint doing a local curl by passing in the client certificate information like so.

What am I doing wrong?

```
sudo curl --cacert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem https://127.0.0.1:2379/metrics -L --cert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-kubemaster-rwva1-prod-2.pem --key /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-kubemaster-rwva1-prod-2-key.pem^C
```

Comment: Using the same client certificates, can you curl `10.0.0.222:2379/metrics`, `10.0.0.221:2379/metrics`, and `10.0.0.220:2379/metrics` from wherever you are opening the prometheus GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `scheme: https` for HTTPS scraping.